# User defined user permissions

Tags: django, permissions, user-permissions

I'm not even sure how to fully ask this question so my googles haven't turned up much.

So I have users, (obv) and they have an entity they're gonna be able to populate called a wallet. A user should have read write and delete permissions on a waller they create

Naturally superadmins should have access to everything. But I want the users to be able to give other users read and / or write access. But regular staff should also have access.

Do I just create a foreign key on the wallet populated with the user id's and boolean for read, write and delete access?

Assuming I do that how do I handle
Staff and super admin access?

Do I like set up a view for a list of wallets that checks to see if you're an admin or staff and if not then checks if you have access and only displays those? And then only allow you to edit or delete if you have those boolean set?

Does that make sense?